# retrieving data from jsonp api that contains pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I'm a little stuck on how I can retrieve all data from a **jsonp api** when the data is split in pages. The callback looks like this:

```
{
entries: [],
page: 1,
pages: 101,
posts: 10054
}
```

the code under only gets me results from page 1, but I would like to get results from all 101 pages. If I add a query to the url like : `&page=2` or `&page=3` I can access objects from that page only, what I'm trying to is access all objects from all pages in one go....
would appreciate some help :)

```
$.getJSON('http://hotell.difi.no/api/jsonp/mattilsynet/smilefjes/tilsyn?callback=?', function(data){

var html = "";

$.each(data.entries, function(key,value){
    html += '<p>' + value.navn + '</p>';
})

$('#test').html(html);

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make first call to get the number of pages and in next calls you can loop through them.
Try below code

```js
$.getJSON('http://hotell.difi.no/api/jsonp/mattilsynet/smilefjes/tilsyn?callback=?', function(data) {
  var pages = data.pages;
  for (var i = 1; i <= data.pages; i++) {
    $.getJSON('http://hotell.difi.no/api/jsonp/mattilsynet/smilefjes/tilsyn?callback=?&page=' + i, function(data) {

      $('#test').append("Page " + data.page + " Data >> ");

      var html = "";
      $.each(data.entries, function(key, value) {
        html += '<p>' + value.navn + '</p>';
      })
      $('#test').append(html);
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsonp using $.ajax() not by $.getJSON(). and you have to declare your callback method in your javascript code

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
$.ajax({
        url: "http://hotell.difi.no/api/jsonp/mattilsynet/smilefjes/tilsyn?callback=myJsonpCallbackMethod",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function( response ) {
            //console.log( response ); // server response
        }
    });
});

function myJsonpCallbackMethod(data){
  alert("Hello");
  console.log( data ); // server response
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)